# Running a file on remote server by ssh respecting shebang line

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

So I have a file. Currently it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print(1)
```

I want to tun it on remote machine. The easy way to do this is to run

```
< test.py ssh server-name python3
```

But what if I don't know that it's a python script (or I may not know that it's python3 not python2) and want to respect its shebang?

I tried

```
< test.py ssh server-name exec /dev/stdin
```

But it fails since `/dev/stdin` is not executable

For simplicity let's assume both of the servers are latest Ubuntu.

So the question is how to run arbitrary script respecting it shebang?

Comment: This isn't a good way to run a local script remotely in general. It only works if the script itself doesn't try to read from standard input.

Comment: @chepner that's a good point (but in my case it's not that relevant since the script is not supposed to read from stdin)

Answer (score 1):

It's the OS that uses the shebang line: see your `execve(2)` man page. The script file must be executable, residing on the system.

You can extract it from the script to use on the remote side: untested:

```
shebang=$(sed -n '1 {s/^#!//p; q}' test.py)
ssh server-name "$shebang -" < test.py
```

Comment: that seem to work, but it's probably not equivalent in general case. (e.g who knows how it works if there no shebang, it allows several arguments for a command in shebang, etc). It would be nice to give this job back to kernel. Meanwhile, probably goodol' copy+chmod+run seems more trustworhy